# Writing a MySQL Events to update the table

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning all, i want to create an event in MySQL that will UPDATE the table after a particular no of days, i have a dateAdded column , i needed the event to take the value of the dateAdded column and check it with the current date if it's >= 365 days it should update a column called status and change the value from 0 to 1.
Any tips.
Thank you.

@cyberomin. Pls i will appreciate code a sample too. Thank's y'all.

Comment: What  exactly is your question about - how to set up the trigger, or how to set up the PHP code to do the stuff? The former will totally depend on your server and whether you have cron jobs available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a PHP script with 1 query and execute it daily with a cron job.

```
UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE dateAdded <= '$whatever'
```

Just replace **$whatever** with your timestamp 365 days ago.

Comment: So what you are saying in essence is that i should set up a cron job against using Events? Which is best and more efficient?

Comment: To be fair, as the job is only running once daily, it's not really necessary to worry too much about efficiency, the query shouldn't be particularly demanding unless you will have many thousands of rows.